# window azure Unable to make the session state request to the session state server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure-web-app-service

could please tell me how to resolve this error in windows azure. In my localhost system, code is working fine but windows azure application is not working its throwing error.

> Unable to make the session state request to the session state server. Please ensure that the ASP.NET State service is started and that the client and server ports are the same.  If the server is on a remote machine, please ensure that it accepts remote requests by checking the value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\aspnet_state\Parameters\AllowRemoteConnection.  If the server is on the local machine, and if the before mentioned registry value does not exist or is set to 0, then the state server connection string must use either 'localhost' or '127.0.0.1' as the server name.

we our i login my application i got this error

In web.config file i added some codes.

instance of this code

`<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" cookieless="false" timeout="60" />`

we added this code

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="RedisSessionProvider">
  <providers>
    <!--<add name="RedisSessionProvider" 
         host = "127.0.0.1" [String]
         port = "" [number]
         accessKey = "" [String]
         ssl = "false" [true|false]
         throwOnError = "true" [true|false]
         retryTimeoutInMilliseconds = "0" [number]
         databaseId = "0" [number]
         applicationName = "" [String]
       />;-->
    <add name="RedisSessionProvider" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" port="6380" host="movie2.redis.cache.windows.net" accessKey="m7PNV60CrvKpLqMUxosC3dSe6kx9nQ6jP5del8TmADk=" ssl="true" />
    <!--<add name="MySessionStateStore" type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider" host="127.0.0.1" accessKey="" ssl="false" />;-->
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

in C# code we used stored session like this

```
SessionService.SUser
```

database connection was working fine but this session state only not working. could you please tell me some solution.

Comment: This guide may help. http://ihostazure.com/asp-net-state-service-tutorial-implementing-state-server-session-in-asp-net/

Comment: Hi Muhammad Saqlain local machine means your solution is ok but i am telling windows azure throwing like this error. local machine working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Check ASP.NET State Service is working

```
1) Start–> Administrative Tools –> Services

2) right click over the ASP.NET State Service and click “start”
```

also

> ```
>  check default port (42424) is available and your system does not have a firewall that is blocking the port on your system
> ```

Comment: Hi @Midhun Mundayadan local system its working fine i asking windows azure server its throwing error msg. so how i will start state service

Comment: I think it is better to create a virtual machine for your current application and configuring azure

Comment: I have VM for current application but if i open services i didnt get ASP.NET State Service so how i will start?